Snippet en VSCode para HTML
Estoy tratando de realizar un snippet para un proyecto que estoy realizando en HTML. Sin embargo, al declarar su estructura y llamar al snippet, no se presenta bien.
Así es como lo declaré:
    {
        "Ejercicio": {
        "prefix": "ejer",
        "body": [
            "<section data-type="sect2">
    
                <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>
          
                <p></p>
          
                <section data-type="sect3">
          
                    <h3>Solución</h3>
                      
                    <figure>      
                        <figcaption></figcaption>
                        <img src="" alt=""/>
                    </figure>
          
                    <p></p>
          
                </section>
          
            </section>"
            ],
            "description": "Ejercicio"
         }
    }

Y cada que lo llamo, el resultado es el siguiente:
    <section data-type=
    >
    2
    sect3

No sé realmente cuál sea el error.
Cabe recalcar que mi proyecto está haciendo uso de la herramienta The Magic Book Project.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! No entiendo cual es el problema, y como llegas de ese json a esa salida.. Si el problema es la herramienta, deberias hablarlo con ellos...

@gbianchi Entiendo. Tengo también cuenta en Mathematics Stack Exchange y Stack Overflow en ingles. Lo de la herramienta era información extra porque sucede que a veces eso ayuda. O me han podido ofrecer mejor ayuda con eso. Mi único problema es que no estoy familiarizado con el lenguaje para de programador para expresarme mejor.
Lo que quiero en mi código, y que funcione cada que llamo a mi snipped es que todo lo que se encuentra dentro de body se replique con el simple hecho de llamar la función ejer, tal como hace un snipped. No sé si me explico.

Como se supone que llamas a eso? como es que lo ejecutas?

Tu problema es que no está escapando las comillas dobles, y las estas usando tanto para delimitar el contenido de body como internamente para los atributos HTML.  Cambia la comilla doble al inicio de "<section  y la del final donde pones  </section>" por comillas simples (apóstrofes) de esta forma '<section y </section>' y seguramente te funcionará mejor

@masterguru Muchas gracias, pero sigue sin funcionar. Ahora el resultado de cambiar las comillas en '<section y </section>' cuando llamo a ejer es:
`sect2
2
sect3`

Pareciera ser que solo esta agregando lo que esta en comillas dobles y no entiendo de donde podría salir ese dos extra.

Snippet*. Haciendo pruebas en vscode.dev noté que tu snippet, incluso corregido, tenía errores de sintaxis. Viendo los mensajes de error al colocar el mouse encima, deduje que cada línea del snippet debe estar separada por comas (no funciona con enters), además de que cada línea debe contar con comillas dobles. Esto, y escapando las comillas simples en los atributos (como src o alt), deberían resolver el problema.

@padaleiana Muchas Gracias!! Te agradezco también por corregir mis errores en la pregunta. En efecto, pude arreglar el problema con el snippet!

En ese caso, pon como respuesta (en base a [answer]) lo que realmente ha resuelto tu problema, y acepta tal respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.

Como me comentaron, el problema estaba en la sintaxis del snippet. Cada línea necesitaba estar entre comillas dobles "" y separadas por una coma ,. Además, para las comillas dobles dentro de los atributos de mi código, era necesario escapar dichas comillas, ya sea sustituyendo las comillas dobles por comillas simples ', o utilizando una diagonal antes de la comilla doble de esta manera \". Así, el snippet quedaría de esta forma:
{
"Ejercicio": {
"prefix": "ejer",
"body": [
    "<section data-type=\"sect2\">",

    "   <h2>Ejercicio 2</h2>",
  
    "   <p></p>",
  
    "   <section data-type=\"sect3\">",
  
    "       <h3>Solución</h3>",
              
    "       <figure>",      
    "           <figcaption></figcaption>",
    "           <img src=\"\" alt=\"\"/>",
    "       </figure>",
  
    "       <p></p>",
  
    "   </section>",
  
    "</section>",
    ],
    "description": "Ejercicio"
 }

}
